# How to disallow null as a value in json4s deserialization

Tags: scala, jackson, json4s

I'm deserializing data from json into case classes and just came across some malformed json providing me `null` for a non-optional object. I would prefer this to be parser failure, instead of setting the field value to `null`. That way i could safely assume that my case classes are properly populated if they parse, but I can't seem to find a way to configure the parser for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to initialize a field with null value and then use "@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)" to ignore the field while deserialization if there wasn't any value assigned to it.

You can check for the existence of the field and interpret it as being null or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jackson deserializer see:

[Deserialization sample](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/custom-deserializer-in-jackson-and-validation.html)

and:

[Another Deserialization sample](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

You can also Deserialize field:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = SomeDeserializer.class)
private String definition;
```

and than do validation in Deserializer.